# Annoying right margin

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Just started to practice with bootstrap so sorry if the question is a little dumb. But whatever I've tried, can't get rid of this blank space from the right (idk if it's margin or something else). Tried setting margin 0 to almost every class/tag in the following code, setting different width, etc. Please help to clarify what am I doing wrong?

[image]

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>CNN homepage</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="bootstrap\dist\css\Bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->



      <style>
        :root {
          --jumbotron-padding-y: 3rem;
        }

        .jumbotron {
          padding-top: var(--jumbotron-padding-y);
          padding-bottom: var(--jumbotron-padding-y);
          margin-bottom: 0;
          background-color: #fff;
        }
        @media (min-width: 768px) {
          .jumbotron {

          }
        }

        .jumbotron p:last-child {
          margin-bottom: 0;
        }

        .jumbotron-heading {
          font-weight: 300;
        }

        .jumbotron .container {
          max-width: 40rem;
        }

        footer {
          padding-top: 3rem;
          padding-bottom: 3rem;
        }

        footer p {
          margin-bottom: .25rem;
        }



        /* My code*/


        .col-sm {
          border: 2px solid black;
          display: flex;
          align-items: center;
          justify-content: center;
          background-color: #CB0003;
          width: 100%;


        }

        .container {margin: 0;
          padding: 0;
        border: 2px solid black;
        width:1500px;
          }

        .album {margin: 0;
          padding: 0;
        border: 2px solid black;
        width:100%;}

        footer {margin: 0;
          padding: 0;
        border: 2px solid black;
        width:100%;}

        header {margin: 0;
          padding: 0;
        border: 2px solid black;
        width:100%;}

      </style>


</head>
  <body>



     <header>
        <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm">
          One of three columns
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm" id="img_container">
          <img id="logo" src="07_homewok_cnn_IMG\cnns.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm">
          One of three columns
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>  

        </header>
    <main role="main">



      <div class="album py-5 bg-light">
        <div class="container">

          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
                <img class="card-img-top" data-src="holder.js/100px225?theme=thumb&bg=55595c&fg=eceeef&text=Thumbnail" alt="Card image cap">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                  <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                    <div class="btn-group">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">View</button>
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Edit</button>
                    </div>
                    <small class="text-muted">9 mins</small>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
                <img class="card-img-top" data-src="holder.js/100px225?theme=thumb&bg=55595c&fg=eceeef&text=Thumbnail" alt="Card image cap">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                  <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                    <div class="btn-group">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">View</button>
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Edit</button>
                    </div>
                    <small class="text-muted">9 mins</small>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
                <img class="card-img-top" data-src="holder.js/100px225?theme=thumb&bg=55595c&fg=eceeef&text=Thumbnail" alt="Card image cap">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                  <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                    <div class="btn-group">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">View</button>
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Edit</button>
                    </div>
                    <small class="text-muted">9 mins</small>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4">
              <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
                <img class="card-img-top" data-src="holder.js/100px225?theme=thumb&bg=55595c&fg=eceeef&text=Thumbnail" alt="Card image cap">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                  <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                    <div class="btn-group">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">View</button>
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Edit</button>
                    </div>
                    <small class="text-muted">9 mins</small>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
                <img class="card-img-top" data-src="holder.js/100px225?theme=thumb&bg=55595c&fg=eceeef&text=Thumbnail" alt="Card image cap">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                  <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                    <div class="btn-group">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">View</button>
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Edit</button>
                    </div>
                    <small class="text-muted">9 mins</small>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
                <img class="card-img-top" data-src="holder.js/100px225?theme=thumb&bg=55595c&fg=eceeef&text=Thumbnail" alt="Card image cap">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                  <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                    <div class="btn-group">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">View</button>
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Edit</button>
                    </div>
                    <small class="text-muted">9 mins</small>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4">
              <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
                <img class="card-img-top" data-src="holder.js/100px225?theme=thumb&bg=55595c&fg=eceeef&text=Thumbnail" alt="Card image cap">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                  <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                    <div class="btn-group">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">View</button>
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Edit</button>
                    </div>
                    <small class="text-muted">9 mins</small>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
                <img class="card-img-top" data-src="holder.js/100px225?theme=thumb&bg=55595c&fg=eceeef&text=Thumbnail" alt="Card image cap">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                  <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                    <div class="btn-group">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">View</button>
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Edit</button>
                    </div>
                    <small class="text-muted">9 mins</small>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
                <img class="card-img-top" data-src="holder.js/100px225?theme=thumb&bg=55595c&fg=eceeef&text=Thumbnail" alt="Card image cap">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                  <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                    <div class="btn-group">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">View</button>
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Edit</button>
                    </div>
                    <small class="text-muted">9 mins</small>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </main>

    <footer class="text-muted">
      <div class="container">
        <p class="float-right">
          <a href="#">Back to top</a>
        </p>
        <p>Album example is &copy; Bootstrap, but please download and customize it for yourself!</p>
        <p>New to Bootstrap? <a href="../../">Visit the homepage</a> or read our <a href="../../getting-started/">getting started guide</a>.</p>
      </div>
    </footer>

    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you post screen shot of your problem?

Comment: Nihal, have added screenshot.

Comment: try after removing py-5 class

Answer (score 0):

There is a **margin(-15px)** from left and right in *row* class in bootstrap. Change it to 0 or just add to the *row* class *no-gutters*

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. It turns out that .container class sets a fixed size of the block and I needed to use .container-fluid class. Thanks everyone for help).